# Dynatable and checkbox. Is it possible to refresh a table when I select a checkbox?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

The question is short. Is there a way to use a DynaTable http://www.dynatable.com , and to filter the results when check-box is selected?

For example, if there is a check box "males", then I would like for the page to list all the males. I don't have a code example as this is the only functionality I need and didn't find in the documentation.

Comment: I also want to know

Comment: I forgot that I had a question open for this, so I forgot to post the answer @EduardoDallmann, but I was able to do this. Please check the answer below, it might give you some hint.

Answer (score 0):

> *Disclaimer*: This is definitely not an answer, as I am pasting some parts that can give a hint, but please do update the answer if you
>   find a better explanation.

This is possible to do, not sure what part of the code made this affect, but please check some of the code below, it might give you a hint.

```
$('#persons-table').dynatable
  features:
    paginate: true
    perPageSelect: true
    search: false

  dataset:
    perPageDefault: 50
    perPageOptions: [50,100, 250, 500]
  inputs:
    queries: $('#person-type')
  readers:
    _rowReader: (index, tr, record) ->
```

And if we have additional code like this:

```
  $('#persons-table').bind 'dynatable:init', (e, dynatable) ->
    self.dynatable = dynatable
    dynatable.queries.functions['person-type'] = (record, queryValue) ->
      if (queryValue== 'male')
        return record.person_type == 'male'
      else
        return false
```